# Laravel sessions permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, сессия, apache2

Есть LAMP и есть Laravel 5.4. Apache2 работает под пользователем www-data. Но Laravel почему-то файлы сессий создаёт под пользователем ubuntu, и сам-же, пытаясь их перезаписать, выдаёт мне permission_denied. Вангую, что дело тут в том, что он их создаёт с правами 644. Пользователь ubuntu у меня является членом группы www-data, и было бы не страшно, если бы Laravel создавал сессии хотя бы с правами 664. Но как это сделать? Во-первых. И во-вторых, почему он создаёт эти файлы с владельцем ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косяк был в правах на папки из-за того, что проект крутится под Vargant'ом. Нужно в `Vagrantfile` жёстко прописать, что такая-то дирректория монтируется в такое-то место с таким-то юзером и такими-то правами. Например:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "projects/test.dev", "/var/www/test.dev", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", create: true,  mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=755"]
```