# apache2 + php5 permission denied

Tags: файлы, apache2, права, php5

В который раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой Permission denied при попытке вызвать mkdir(). Много гуглил, пытался задавать [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655699/laravel-sessions-permission-denied) здесь, но ответа не получил.

Сейчас такая ситуация. Есть путь условно **/var/www/project**. Скрипту нужно создать путь **/var/www/project/files/6**. Права на папку **/var/www/project** я выставил 777. Владельцем сделал **www-data:www-data**. Всё равно отказывается создавать такую папку. Помогите раз и навсегда разобраться с этой проблемой, подкиньте годный ман. Вроде и в линуксах не новичок, и на PHP пишу давно, а вот вякий раз как сталкиваюсь начинаются непонятки. Apache2 стартует под юзером **www-data**.

Comment: Вы бы хоть вывод `ls -la /var/www/project` привели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косяк в том, что проект работает под Вагрантом. При монировании папок из хостовой системы в гостевую надо жёстко задавать юзера, группу и права доступа. Например:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "projects/test.dev", "/var/www/test.dev", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", create: true,  mount_options: ["dmode=755,fmode=755"]
```

Answer (score 0):

для эксперимента попробуйте chown -R apache:apache /var/www/project/files
если сработает, то включайте апача в группу www-data

Comment: Если верить ТС, apache работает под пользователем `www-data`